# multiple records due to yes/no

Tags: sql, ms-access

My query pulls records from a table based on a UserID, Priority (Yes/No), then assigns a review date based on an iif statement.

```
SELECT Roster.UserID, 
EventLog.Priority, 
IIf([EventLog]![Priority]=True, [EventLog]![Date], Date()-183) AS [Review Date]
FROM EventLog 
INNER JOIN Roster 
ON EventLog.UserID = Roster.UserID
GROUP BY Roster.UserID, EventLog.Priority, 
         IIf([EventLog]![Priority]=True, [EventLog]![Date], Date()-183);
```

As not every recory will have a priority (Yes) indicator, my query is returning both Yes and No options for those users that have a (Yes).

```
Query Results ex.
UserID   Priority     Review Date
abc123     Yes          5-19-2012
abc123     No           5-22-2012
qwe456     No           5-22-2012
yip552     Yes          3-10-2012
yip552     No           5-22-2012
```

How do I have it return only the Yes answer for those UserIDs that have one and keep the NO calculation for those that dont?

Comment: Safe to assume this is another query related to access? If so, please make sure to add the access (`ms-access`) tag to your question.

Comment: Sorry Brad and rest of board.  I have tagged appropriately.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Please be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use Max or Min, depending in the data stored, the word "Yes" will be Max, but the value -1 will be Min:

```
SELECT 
  Roster.UserID, 
  Max(EventLog.Priority), 
  Max(IIf([EventLog]![Priority]=True, [EventLog]![Date], Date()-183)) AS [Review Date]
FROM EventLog 
INNER JOIN Roster 
ON EventLog.UserID = Roster.UserID
GROUP BY Roster.UserID
```

<s>You should be able to choose Expression for `IIf([EventLog]![Priority]=True, [EventLog]![Date], Date()-183) AS [Review Date]`, so it need not be included in GROUP BY</s>

You can choose Max for the IIf statement, too.

Comment: Remou, I tried the SQL as posted and received still see the other record. The yes no option changed to 0 & -1 so I attempted changing the code to...    SELECT Roster.UserID, Min(EventLog.Priority) AS MinOfPriority, IIf(EventLog!Priority=True,EventLog!Date,Date()-183) AS [Review Date]
FROM EventLog INNER JOIN Roster ON EventLog.UserID = Roster.UserID
GROUP BY Roster.UserID, IIf(EventLog!Priority=True,EventLog!Date,Date()-183);    The other value still remains.

Comment: Remou, I think I had mis understood your answer.  After playing around with the context in the expression builder i just wrapped the iif statement with Min(...code...) and used expression as suggested and it works Great!!!  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Snap, I just changed that. :)